# Python documentations frontpage

Tags: python, python-sphinx

http://docs.python.org/3/

I would like to mimic python documentations fronpage for my own project. Trouble is every other page has show source link in the sidebar except for the front page.

How can I archive the same effect on new sphinx project?

Comment: If all else fails, check out the repository.

Comment: I've tried looking at the doc directory of pythons source code but all I could find was contents.rst that included standard toctree. I haven't found how does it make it look like it does. My toctree's just output a standard list.

Comment: You're probably after their theme then, because the theme does things like formatting the index page.

Comment: When then the question can be slightly altered to how can I alter my current theme (https://github.com/snide/sphinx_rtd_theme) to have this kind of layout.

Comment: The default theme for sphinx is the theme for python 2.7 documentation but it still doesn't format my toctree the same as their site. Something funky going on over here.

Comment: Huh. Strange, and it's possible that I'm way off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation front page at http://docs.python.org/3/ is based on [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) templates.

- The top-level template is [layout.html](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Doc/tools/templates/layout.html), which extends a [Sphinx template](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/themes/basic/layout.html) with the same name.
- [indexcontent.html](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Doc/tools/templates/indexcontent.html) provides the structure for the main content.
- The sidebar has its own special template: [indexsidebar.html](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Doc/tools/templates/indexsidebar.html).

The theme is called [pydoctheme](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Doc/tools/pydoctheme) (`html_theme = 'pydoctheme'` in [conf.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Doc/conf.py)).

More information about templates and themes in Sphinx:

- http://sphinx-doc.org/templating.html
- http://sphinx-doc.org/theming.html